# Set progress state in react to handle download feedback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a handleDownload() function in react that downloads selected files from an s3 bucket to my machine.

I've added a setProgress() to increment for each file downloaded.

It is currently setting progress state after all files have downloaded instead of after each file.

```
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [checkedPlayers, setCheckedPlayers] = useState([]);

const handleDownload = () => {
console.log("handleDownload");
setLoading(true);
let count = 0;

if (selectedPlayers.length > 0) {
  const hr = 3600;
  const signedUrlExpireSeconds = hr * 1;
  const s3 = new S3Client({
    region: region,
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
    }
  });

  const downloadPromises = selectedPlayers.map(async player => {
    const myKey = player.Key;
    const bucketParams = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: myKey,
    };
    try {
      const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, new GetObjectCommand(bucketParams), { expiresIn: signedUrlExpireSeconds });
      console.log(`Signed URL for player ${player.Key}: ${url}`);
      count++;
      setProgress(Math.round(count / selectedPlayers.length * 100));
      return new jsDownloader({
        url: url,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

  Promise.all(downloadPromises)
    .then(() => {
      setLoading(false);
      setCheckedPlayers([]);
      setProgress(0);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

};

Comment: What is `jsDownloader`? The only thing you're awaiting for each _player_ is the signed URL generation

Comment: jsDownloader is an npm package to help with downloading files.

Comment: Which one, specifically? How are you importing it into this component?

Comment: js-file-downloader, 

import jsDownloader from "js-file-downloader";

Comment: A link would have been preferable. Do you mean this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-downloader

Comment: Sorry, yes that is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the only thing you await for each *player* is the signed URL generation. Compared to the download, this would be quite quick and would appear like your *progress* was complete before the downloads were.

Add your progress counter to the completion of each download promise instead. You could even make use of the [process](https://github.com/AleeeKoi/js-file-downloader#process-for-checking-download-status) hook in the js-file-downloader library to have extra granular control over the progress value.

Start by being able to track individual download progress as well as the total

```js
// for tracking individual file progress
const [fileProgress, setFileProgress] = useState({});

// total progress
const progress = useMemo(() => {
  const values = Object.values(fileProgress);
  if (values.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return Math.floor(
    (values.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0) / values.length) * 100
  );
}, [fileProgress]);
```

then update each file's progress as received

```js
const handleDownload = async () => {
  if (selectedPlayers.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  setLoading(true);
  // initialise all progress
  setFileProgress(
    Object.fromEntries(selectedPlayers.map(({ Key }) => [Key, 0]))
  );

  const downloadPromises = selectedPlayers.map(async (player, index) => {
    const bucketParams = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: player.Key,
    };
    try {
      const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, new GetObjectCommand(bucketParams), {
        expiresIn: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
      });
      console.log(`Signed URL for player ${player.Key}: ${url}`);

      // wait for the download
      await new jsDownloader({
        url: url,
        process: ({ lengthComputable, loaded, total }) => {
          if (lengthComputable) {
            setFileProgress((prev) => ({
              ...prev,
              [player.Key]: loaded / total,
            }));
          }
        },
      });

      // mark complete
      setFileProgress((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [player.Key]: 1,
      }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });

  await Promise.all(downloadPromises);
  setLoading(false);
  setCheckedPlayers([]);
  // setFileProgress({}); <- not sure I'd bother
};
```

Note: don't initialise the S3 client in the function or even in your component. Move it out so it's only created once

[image: Edit adoring-hopper-5jqhwx]

Comment: I've refactored my code with your code above and moved the S3 client initialization outside of the component but am still only getting progress update at the end. I looked at the CodeSandbox example and the structure on there looks quite different.

Comment: The sandbox contains a bunch of mocks / fakes for the AWS and js-file-downloader parts. You can ignore those. The important part is in the component which is the same code as in my answer

Comment: I've structured the code as you have above and I'm still getting progress update after all have downloaded.

Comment: How many files are you attempting to download? Most browsers can handle ~5 simultaneous downloads so if you're not trying more than that, it's not really surprising that they'd all finish around the same time assuming they're all of similar size. Try playing with the network throttling in your browser dev-tools or try more files.

Comment: I tried as few as 3 and as many as 20 - same results

Comment: What do you see if you render the `fileProgress` object like in the sandbox, ie `<pre>fileProgress: {JSON.stringify(fileProgress, null, 2)}</pre>`? Have you also tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: It looks correct. All the file numbers are changing like in sandbox but my progress percentage is not updating.

Comment: I created a sandbox for my code just so you can see - isn't rigged to run.
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-water-l82j5k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @sbaden stop creating things within your component. Your `CircularProgressWithLabel` should definitely be declared outside as its own stand-alone component. I've updated my sandbox link with your progress component and it still works fine

Comment: Thank you for the learning opportunity - I didn't realize I shouldn't be using functions within my components.

Comment: not sure what is going wrong on my end. The fileProgress is still not updating in my download button. When I render <pre>fileProgress: {JSON.stringify(fileProgress, null, 2)}</pre> it displays all of the download statuses for the files correctly.